# What does dx = dy mean formally?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I have a circle with circumference $X$ and charge density $\lambda$ and have to find a potential at distance $a$ from the center. I understand how to do that, the physics way is to write $E_x = \dfrac{K\lambda a l}{(a^2+x^2)^{\dfrac{3}{2}}},$

and then say that this implies $\mathbb d E_x = \dfrac{K\lambda a}{(a^2+x^2)^{\dfrac{3}{2}}}\mathbb d l,$  and then integrate with respect to $\mathbb d l$ from $0$ to $2 \pi x$.

But what does $\mathbb dE = ... \mathbb d l$? mean mathematically

I tried to approach it with taking the total derivative of $E_x$ which would work only if I viewed $E_x$ as function of only $l$, because then I get

$\mathbb dE = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial l} (\dfrac{K\lambda a l}{(a^2+x^2)^{\dfrac{3}{2}}}) \mathbb d l = \dfrac{K\lambda a}{(a^2+x^2)^{\dfrac{3}{2}}} \mathbb d l .$

If I would take this approach (which I doubt works every time), then I have no idea how to integrate total differentials.

Am I on the right track at least? Or is there some part of math I am missing?

Comment: It means they increase/decrease with the same rate (talking about $dx=dy$).

Comment: "$\mathbb dE = ... \mathbb d l$" signifies the electric field(dE) due to the small element of charge(dl).

Comment: Your title is not clear.

Comment: Well I understand that, but I am trying to find a rigorous mathematical way how to perceive it. Like what theory is behind saying that if $\Delta E = f(x) \Delta x$, then $ \mathbb d E = f(x) \mathbb d x$.

Comment: You are basically right... You consider $E_x$ as a function of $l$ and you derive it. As you can see, the result contains again $x$.

Comment: @LukášMoudrý you'll find physicists are a little loose and fast with formality. In the end, every measurement is a rational number so considering everything an approximation more or less works.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I understand and know that. But usually there is some formal way behind what they do – and that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: You have to apply the operation to a function: $\dfrac {d}{dy}f(y)$ and $f(y)$ is a certain symbolic expression containing (among others) $y$.

Comment: @LukášMoudrý How do you define $dE$ formally?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh okay, that makes sense. But when I now take this to the disk I have something like $\Delta E = \frac {Ka \sigma \pi x^2 \Delta x}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$ and then doing $\frac{\mathbb d}{\mathbb d x} E$ results in something nasty. But doing it the physics way, you just differentiate $x^2$ to $2x \mathbb d x$, which still makes me confused from the math point of view.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Well that is something I am trying to find out, if there is any formal explanation.

Comment: It's the same as saying that the area of the annular disk of radius $r$ and width $\delta r$ is $ 2\pi r \delta r$. Integrating this expression in $r$ between $0$ and $R$ you get the area of the disk of radius $R$.

Comment: @LukášMoudrý I'm not sure there is a meaningful way to do this without appealing to the integral in the first place. I would note that Newton did all of his physics without understanding what he was doing and Euler built a mountain of analysis informally as well. Sometimes you can just go for it.

Comment: It means that the differential 1-forms $$\mathrm{d}E_x \qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{K\lambda a}{(a^2+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,\mathrm{d}l, $$ when they are restricted onto the submanifold $$M=\left\{(E_x,l)\in\mathbb{R}^2: E_x = \frac{K\lambda a l}{(a^2+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right\}, $$ are identical. More intuitively, when $E_x$ and $l$ are restricted to the surface defined by the relation $E_x = (K\lambda a l)/(a^2+x^2)^{3/2}$ (with all the other variables frozen), they induce the same 'rates of change'.

Comment: This also means that, if you consider different relations or allow some other variables to vary, then they induce different submanifolds and hence the restrictions of the above 1-forms onto them can be no longer identical.

Comment: @SangchulLee Amazing! Thx! So to grasp the math behind it on deeper level, I have to go to manifolds and forms?

Comment: That's correct :) However, besides that the language of differential manifolds provides a rigorous justification of differential, I see no harm to leave this technicality as a 'black box' and proceed. The key idea is to know which relations you are working with, which will in turn determine the relations between the differentials. (In particular, seemingly the same notation may actually refer to different things if they came from unrelated or incompatible relations.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Well, yes, I could leave it as a blackbox, but my brain just wanna know :D Thx a lot again

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% familiar with your example so I will answer with an equally valid example. Say you want to compute the area of the disk of radius $R$ and you only know the formula for the length of a circle of radius $R$ ($2\pi R$) and calculus.

One way is to draw the annulus between the disk of radius $r+\delta r$ and $r$ and compute its area. Here $\delta r$ is just a small quantity. I will be more precise later.

The area of this annulus is approximately given by

$$
\delta A = 2 \pi r \delta r .
$$

Note that strictly speaking the formula is wrong, and in fact it is only valid up to linear order in $\delta r$. To be more precise we should write

$$
\delta A = 2 \pi r \delta r + O(\delta r^2) .
$$

which tells us that the error of the first formula is of order $\delta r^2$. If we knew already the formula for the area of the disk we could write

$$
\delta A = \pi \big[ (r +\delta r)^2 -r^2 \big] = \pi (2r \delta r +\delta r^2 ), 
$$

but we don't.

Now to find the area of the disk of radius $R$ you can simply integrate $ \delta A$ from $0$ to $R$. To be more precise what we are doing here is really evaluating the integral as a limit of Riemann sums.

$$
A(R) = \int_0^R dr 2 \pi r = \lim_{\delta r\to 0} \sum_j  2\pi r_j \delta r
$$

In this form it does not matter whether we use the first or second expression (or third) for $\delta A$ because the term $O(\delta r^2)$ contributes zero to the sum in the limit $\delta r\to 0$. (If you want to be explicit you can choose $\delta r = R/N$, $r_j= j \delta r$, $j=0,1,\ldots,N-1$.

Now we learn that the area is

$$
A(R) = \pi R^2
$$

You can indeed differentiate and  obtain

$$
\frac{dA}{dr} (r) = 2 \pi r 
$$

which you can "interpret" as

$$
dA = 2\pi r dr. 
$$

This very powerful interpretation, is allowed because, after Leibniz, we write the derivative as the limit of the incremental ratio.

In this context this is more than sufficient. In differential geometry one can say that $dr$ (and $dA$) are 1-forms but I would say this is beyond the scope of the question (one needs a definition of forms in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

In the way you used it, it seems like $df = g\,dl$ means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial l} = g$. If $f$ is a function of more than one variable, this is not equivalent to the interpretation of $df$ as a one form.